# Remove watermark from pdf of images

Tags: pdf, image-processing, watermark

I have a pdf consiting of page scans and they have they have an annoying watermark that appears as a grey image in the middle of pages difficulting reading. Since the pdf is made of image files there is no watermark object to be manipulated directly, so this is an image processing problem. Is there a program that can help me accomplish this task?

DUPLICATE CONCERNS EDIT: The question is not a duplicate of:
[How to remove a watermark from a PDF file?](https://superuser.com/questions/455462/how-to-remove-a-watermark-from-a-pdf-file)
as I have made rather clear in the original question, the problem here is one of programmatic processing of IMAGES to remove a pattern. The images happened to be compiled as a pdf file as they come from scanning a physical document.

Comment: If the watermark is part of a flat image there's not a great deal you can do with it, as there's nothing 'behind' it to make visible. That's the whole point of a watermark; presumably someone wants you to pay for the unsullied version.

Comment: I am sure there are image processing tools to identify and remove such patterns, I just don't know of any efective ones. I also though about possible using an OCR program to extract the content which may ignore de watermark but possible damage the document in other ways which would be impractical since it has hundreths of pages.

Comment: As we can't see the watermark, we can't see how much 'damage' it causes. However, if it's a flat image there is literally nothing 'behind' the watermark to recover. Clever AI structures can try to fill in image details, but text details require a different level of intelligence.